# If a function returns an object it cannot act as constructor function in JS. Is my assumption correct

Tags: javascript, function, return, new-operator

Following code demonstrates the same.

```js
function test(x) {
  this.x = x;
  return {};
}

function test1(x) {
  this.x = x;
}

console.log(new test(1).x); // logs undefined 

console.log(new test1(1).x); // logs 1
```

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Please try to format your code before posting - there's even a preview box

Comment: You're returning a `{}` from first function so it will definitely give you undefined

Comment: it is still a constructor.

Answer (score 2):

> Returns `this` if the function doesn't return its own object.  [**new operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

In your first function you're returning a `{}` so when you access

`new test(x).x`

You're actually accessing `{}.x` which is `undefined`

whereas in your second function

`new test(x).x` is actually accessing the `x` property added on function `test`

Comment: I got confused because of two things 1) If I return a number the code logs 1 2) I was under the impression that returning an object will not make a difference in object creation.

Comment: @SPS `new` returns this in case you don't return anything from function